# Django - Extending an app's model to override its manager

Tags: python, django

Using the `django-tagging` app as an example, I would like to change the manager of the `Tag` model so that I can replace it with an extended one:

```
# mytagging/models.py
from django.db import models
from tagging.models import TagManager, Tag

class MyTagManager(TagManager):
    def update_tags(self, obj, tag_names):
        # My actions
        return super(MyTagManager, self).update_tags(obj, tag_names)
    def add_tag(self, obj, tag_name):
        # My actions
        return super(MyTagManager, self).add_tag(obj, tag_name)

Tag.objects = MyTagManager
```

Now, `Tag.objects = MyTagManager` doesn't work, nor did I expect it to, but it illustrates what I would like to accomplish. I could very well create `class MyTag(Tag)` and set the manager that way, but then it would seem that I would also have to extend every other class that uses `Tag` and change it to `MyTag`.

I tried `Tag.objects = MyTagManager()` to initialize the class, but I get the error `'NoneType' object has no attribute '_meta'` from a query object, it appears.

The above code renders this error when calling `Tag.objects.update_tags(kwargs['instance'], tags)` from admin page:

> unbound method update_tags() must be called with MyTagManager instance
>   as first argument (got LibraryFile instance instead)

The `LibraryFile` model is the one I'm attempting to tag, and should therefore be the second argument instead of first (`self` being first).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Secator's suggestion as part of the solution, I ended up just monkey-patching the `Tag` model itself where needed instead of the `Tag.objects`.

This being the final code:

```
from tagging.models import TagManager, Tag
import tagging

class MyTagManager(TagManager):
    def update_tags(self, obj, tag_names):
        # My actions
        return super(MyTagManager, self).update_tags(obj, tag_names)
    def add_tag(self, obj, tag_name):
        # My actions
        return super(MyTagManager, self).add_tag(obj, tag_name)

class MyTag(Tag):
    objects = MyTagManager()
    class Meta:
        proxy = True

tagging.models.Tag = MyTag
tagging.fields.Tag = MyTag
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [proxy model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#proxy-model-managers) with the different manager:

```
class MyTag(Tag):
    objects = MyTagManager()
    class Meta:
        proxy = True
```

Comment: Nice to know, looks good for extended models which you want to use the same db table as base class. My problem is that `Tag` is used in other Forms and Fields and such, would I also have to extend those to change their usage to `MyTag` since they use `update_tags()`? It would be a lot less code to replace the manager of base class, but I'm not sure if that's possible.